# Interpreting OleDb representation of the database numeric(20, 0) using native C++

Tags: c++, postgresql, oledb

**Context:** I am expanding the old console application that is used to SQL query an SQL server and to store the SELECT result into the DBF table. The application is written in the native C++. It includes `oledb.h` and uses the documented ATL objects (`atldbcli.h`)

```
CCommand<CManualAccessor, CRowset> cmd;
CTable<CManualAccessor, CRowset> dstTable;
```

Then the common buffer is allocated and shared later by the source table and the `dstTable`. The suitable binding of columns to the buffer parts does the conversion when copying to the destination table. So far, so good.

**What I need:** I need to implement the extension where the source table content is interpreted. The values of a row from the source table should be used to build another SQL SELECT command. No problem with strings. However, I need to get the value of the field that is defined as `NUMERIC(20, 0)` in the database. The column type is really of `DBTYPE_NUMERIC`, the `colInfo.bPrecision` shows 20 and `colInfo.bScale` is zero. The lenght of the part of the buffer is 19 bytes

**Buffer content:** The buffer for the field shows the value

```
04 00 01 10 1d 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

I know that the exact value of the field should be 7440 that is 0x1d10. I can see it from the fourth byte of the buffer on. For the quick&dirty hack I cand get the value; however, I would like to understand the details to implement it nicely for any `NUMERIC(x, y)`...

What tell the first three bytes? Are there any ready-to-be-used functions in oledb.h or atldbcli.h to get the value?

Comment: the first byte seems to me like the length of written data, don't know about the rest but one possibility could be that one represents the position of the comma, or the number of characters after it and the other power of 10 (or 2) to apply to the result before putting the comma?! Definitely need more samples to deduce preferably with different settings for numeric

Comment: can I also ask why you're not using libpq which can interpret the data for you and trying to do this yourself, you might get incompatible changes with newer versions of postgresql if you do your own implementation, this is your backend's interpretation, postgresql seems to send numeric with this code `     pq_sendint16(&buf, x.ndigits);
pq_sendint16(&buf, x.weight);
pq_sendint16(&buf, x.sign);
pq_sendint16(&buf, x.dscale);
for (i = 0; i < x.ndigits; i++)
       pq_sendint16(&buf, x.digits[i]);`

Comment: @xception: Thanks for your help. PostgreSQL is only one of the engines that is used as the source of the data. I still need the tool to be for general use -- so, `libpq` is not the option for me. Also, it is used in Windows environment, and the specific goal is to produce DBF tables to feed an old application.

Comment: cool, can you than at least provide more data points so we can figure out how things work? I'd suggest at least 1 negative number, one with fewer bytes used, one with more and something with some decimals after the comma

Comment: @xception: Well, I am searching on how to use the existing implementation of OleDb. I strongly believe it is implemented and there is no reason to reinvent the wheel. The answer can probably be found in the official doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/data/oledb/ole-db-consumer-templates-cpp?view=vs-2019 (It seems that I am just blind to find it.)